# Can't access admin portal after logging in via DRF with Djoser Token Authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, djoser

I am implementing a TokenAuthentication using **Djoser** *djoser.urls.authtoken* via `/api/auth/token/login/`. I can login just fine but when I go to /admin/ it redirects me to Django's admin login page and requires me to login again.

I then realized `/admin/` and `/api/auth/token/login/` are different things. How can I access the admin portal or tell Django to allow me to open `/admin/` when I login via this DRF?

Comment: the Django admin won't provide any API response. Why do you need to access it anyway?

Comment: Apart from that, to access admin you need corresponding permissions

Comment: Basically writers upload their posts via the admin portal... And we are using React to present the article's content on the website... We are now planning to provide a preview route for writers so they can see how their article would look like (from admin portal click 'preview' link then redirect to preview route via React)... The condition to activate preview route is if 'user token' exists which becomes available when user logs in via DRF...

Comment: Eventually, we will stop using Django admin since we are already implementing React... But for now, we want to continue integrating the Django admin for populating the database such as adding posts, activities, etc....

Answer (score -1):

If you want any other users to access the Admin Panel all you have to do is make them a staff member by setting the

> is_staff = models.BooleanField(default="False")

to True, by doing this now Writers can login to the admin panel. Now set permissions such that the writers can only approve posts and nothing else. Good Luck.